# Should I make seperate pages(views) for all the items in .net mvc using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning .net mvc through making a web application.
I have a page for a list of items(for example a list of properties). How should I generate the urls for each of these item? Inside each url there would be a page for more detailed information of the item. Should I manually create each view for each item? There could be thousands of them. Any advise on any tools or methods I could use? Thanks!

Comment: You should create one view for your list and one view for your detailed information panel.

The view with the list should simply be a list of models that you can then render.

The view for the detailed information panel should just take a model for the item you want to render.

I can go into detail if you want me to, but it should be fairly simple to grasp, assuming you understand how MVC and view rendering works. To figure out which view to display etc. use routing and simply from your controller retrieve the correct model for your view.

Comment: did you hear of Scaffolding?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question.  The identification of opportunities for generalization vs. specialization is one of the most important competencies for a software engineer.  And there are a lot of variables.

Two principles you should be aware of:

[Keep it Simple Stupid (KISS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

[Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

N.B. In many ways these principles are in opposition to one another.

You could build a web site with one view for each product.  This is pretty rare because you'd have to build a lot of views.  On the other hand, if you only have a few products and you want to highlight their features using a custom layout (for example, visit [Tesla.com](https://www.tesla.com/)), you might develop View for each and every product.  This does keep it simple, but you may end up repeating yourself a lot.

More commonly (e.g. Amazon.com) there will be one "Product Page" view with code that customizes the page (e.g. fills in the text and image areas) per product.  This is a much more scalable solution, although when you do it that way you need to take the time to develop a rich and flexible data model, because you need a uniform way of representing the content on the page in a database so that the code that populates the View can be completely generic.  This avoids repeating yourself, but it is less simple.

Then there are solutions that are in between.  Maybe half of your products can be represented on a single type of page, but some of them need a different layout (e.g. need to include a size/color UX, or include spec sheets).  So you may end up with a half dozen views, one for each type of product, that cover hundreds of products.

What about other pages?  Like search, homepage, etc.  Well you will need a separate view for each page that is different enough that justifies splitting it off from other views.  For example, if your Search Results page and your Browse By Category page look very similar, you might implement them with a single View and write code to tailor some details about how they look (e.g. change the title).  On the other hand, if they are pretty different it may be less work to implement them as separate Views.  It is all about striking a balance between DRY and KISS.

There are a lot of judgment calls.  If you don't feel comfortable making these judgments, I suggest you find another site that is similar to yours and see how they have broken down their views.  It is usually pretty easy to tell by paying attention to the URL as you click through the UX.